# Как расшифровывается git/hg?

Tags: git, hg

Что такое git, я знаю, а как расшифровывается hg?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mercurial (англ. ртутный, подвижный), он же Hg (от обозначения химического элемента ртути) — кроссплатформенная распределенная система управления версиями, разработанная для эффективной работы с очень большими репозиториями кода. В первую очередь она является консольной программой.